# Only the last item added in the array when looping and calling state setter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that takes files as an argument, then I iterate over those files, and with a `FileReader`, I try to change the state with the file upload information.

But in the end, I always have only the last file. What is wrong with my code?

```
const [fileData, setFileData] = useState<
    {
      name: string;
      isLoading: boolean;
    }[]
  >([]);
  const onDrop = (acceptedFiles: File[]) => {
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadstart = () => {
        setFileData([...fileData, { name: file.name, isLoading: true }]);
      };
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setFileData(
          fileData.map(item => {
            if (file.name === item.name) {
              return { name: item.name, isLoading: true };
            }
            return item;
          }),
        );
      };
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a state setter multiple times in a row, React combines the changes in one render for performance's sake. This is called [state batching](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates).

To update the same state multiple times before the next render, what you are doing in your loop, use an updater function, like so:

```
setFileData((prevFileData) => [...prevFileData, { name: file.name, isLoading: true }]);
```

This way, `prevFileData` will contain the most up-to-date value of `fileData,` which gets updated after a re-render.